# struct messed in socket "recv" function between Linux Client and Windows Server,works fine for windows

Tags: windows, linux, sockets, struct, cross-platform

I got a struct for client and server like this:

```
{
   char type;
   int payloadLen;
   char fileName[50];
   int fileIndex;
   int blockOffset;
   int blockLen;
   char streamingData[MAX];
   int h264fileLayer;
 }
```

in client I recv data like

```
memset(&data_recevied, 0, sizeof(data_received);
recv(sockfd, (char *)&data_received, sizeof(data_received), 0);
```

I use this to receive file sent from server,everything works fine for the first leading couples of files,then it broke,I checked the struct when it broke, seems the struct it received is a mess,and fileIndex is way too large,however the client program works fine in Windows with winsock lib,no broken at all.

I think this has something to do with cross-platform,maybe there is something I missed,really could use help here, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good idea to send this kind of structs between programs. With luck it may work.

There is couple reasons that may cause the problem:

1. Sender uses different kind of alignments than receiver
2. Size of int can be different in different systems
3. Byte order can be different. If both programs runs in PC, then the byte order is not the problem.

You can try to remove padding (alignments) by using:

Linux:

```
typedef struct 
{    
    char type;    
    int payloadLen;   
    ...
}  __attribute__ ((packed)) my_type_t;
```

Windows:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct 
{    
    char type;    
    int payloadLen;   
    ...
} my_type_t;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

If still problems, then use `int32_t` (or some other fixed size type) instead of int.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I added the #pramga pack(push,1) on server before it sends struct to client,same error.or do I have to add that line on every type definition in that struct?server and client share the same struct structure,i.e.same data-defined order,same data type and both server and client is 4bytes for int,and yes they both runs on PC

Comment: If you use "pack" in windows, the you should use attribute "packed" in Linux. I will add example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks,it is working for a little longer now,but still breaks with fileIndex way too large,thanks for trying to help

Comment: BTW,in short future, this program may have to run on android(arm),what you mean by byte order problem?I think since it is converted to char*, there should no byte older problem at all.Thanks a lot

Comment: For example: if size of payloadLen is 4 bytes, and value is 1.
In Little Endian machines (like i386 PC): Bytes are in the following order: 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00. 
In Big Endian machines: Bytes are in the following order: 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01. If you don't handle this, the peer may get value 0x1000000 instead of 1.

Comment: So, if you are going to transfer more complex data structures, consider use of XML or serialization (see answer of Starynkevitch).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using standard [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques, formats or libraries: [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [ASN1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn1), [JSON](http://json.org), [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml), [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/), [s11n](http://s11n.net/) and many many others

Comment: Thanks for your reply,however I don`t have a lot access to the server code,gonna have to deal with it.